# Why do only the controls show up when using HTML5 video on Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-video

I'm using the following HTML5 to display video, but only the controls show up in Chrome. Works fine in Safari and Firefox:

```
<video width="720" height="480" controls="controls" preload="preload">
    <source src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-content/uploads/Reel.ogv" type="video/ogg; codecs=theora,vorbis" >
    <source src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-content/uploads/Reel.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser doesn't support video.
</video>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: One minor thing: Unless you're writing XHTML5, you don't need controls="controls" - <video width="720" height="480" controls preload> is enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks to me like the first `<source>` tag has a malformed type attribute:

```
<source src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-content/uploads/Reel.ogv" type="video/ogg; codecs=theora,vorbis" >
```

should be `type="video/ogg; codecs='theora, vorbis'"` if I remember correctly.  Also just try type="video/ogg".